# We need a script to create a backup of all the files, database and email using third party Cpanel details in PHP

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

We need a script to create a backup of all the files, database and email using Cpanel details in PHP. It should allow to login into any kind of Cpanel. Also it should connect to other cpanel as well not only our cpanel

Example:

```
Add Details Page fields:
--Cpanel Username: 
--Password:
-- Host
-- Port
```

User hit Connect Button.Once connected then we will ask them to back up all files. Once back up start then all the files from their server will transfer to our server. So any one can come to our site and can schedule a back up.

We were able to create the backup of all the files on our server where we are running the code but unable to connect other cpanel server.

Is there a way doing that or not ?

Comment: already tried https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+1+Functions+-+Fileman::fullbackup

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @grey No I need it in codeigniter

Comment: oh yea, sorry, forget what I said, I was confused with the wordpress CPanel :/

Comment: @grey No problem . do you have a solution  ?

Comment: no, but your own answer seems to be alright, just be sure to encrypt that password somehow, just in case someone manages to get their hands on that file

Comment: @grey yes My answer works fine only if I want to take back up of my own site but I want to take back of some other site it won't work that well

Comment: hmm, I'd say it'd be as easy as entering diferent credentials in the variables? but I wouldn't know

Comment: @grey I tried but no success

Comment: then I wouldn't know, can't you get an app line filezilla to run this for you every month/day/etc?

Comment: @grey can you bit explain it

Comment: maybe there is a way to add the connections to filezilla and write a program at executes those connections, telling filezilla to fetch the website and store it on the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include "xmlapi.php";

$source_server_ip = "";
$cpanel_account = ""; // cPanel username
$cpanel_password = ''; // cPanel password 

//Credentials for FTP remote site
$ftphost = ""; // FTP host IP or domain name
$ftpacct = ""; // FTP account
$ftppass = ""; // FTP password
$email_notify = ''; // Email address for backup notification

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($source_server_ip);
$xmlapi->password_auth($cpanel_account,$cpanel_password);
$xmlapi->set_port('2083');

$api_args = array('passiveftp', $ftphost, $ftpacct, $ftppass,$email_notify,21,'/');

$xmlapi->set_output('json');
print $xmlapi->api1_query($cpanel_account,'Fileman','fullbackup',$api_args);
```

?>

The above code is working fine but only for the same server where this code is written